# After accessing adb shell with python, I want to output subdirectories and all files for a specific directory

Tags: python, android

```
def print_files_in_dir(root_dir, prefix):
    files = os.listdir(root_dir)
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(root_dir, file)
        f.write(path + '\n')
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            print_files_in_dir(path, prefix + "    ")
```

The python code above is the code that outputs the window subdirectories and all files, not in the adb shell.

I want to use adb shell to print out certain directories - subdirectories and all files in android.

Answer (score 0):

python version : 3.8.5

Development Environment : Window10

```
command = 'adb shell ls -R /data/data/' + package_name 
subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True, stdout=open('adb_sub_dir.txt', 'w'))
```

Using check_call from subprocess, we found subdirectories and all files through ls -R command in window environment.

For os.popen(), only the window cmd command can be used.
In this case, the Linux command was not available. That's why we excluded it and looked for subprocesses while looking for other methods, which enabled us to use Linux commands in a Windows environment.